# Regular Expression to get 12 numerical numbers

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am new to the regular expression.
How to check that user inputs are between 0-12 numerical numbers in regular expression?

```
Ex:'012','012345','012345678901'
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Numerical numbers? As opposed to what? Non-numerical numbers?

Comment: `\d{1,12}` (Sorry this wouldn't work for zero digit numbers :) )

Comment: @L.B - Just to say that in .NET, `\d` will match on any numeric Unicode character (so Arabic numerals will also match, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
^[0-9]{0,12}$
```

- `^` -> Starts with (no chars before).
- `[0-9]` -> Any char from 0 to 9. Can be replaced with `\d` to match any numerals from different encodings.
- `{0,12}` -> 0 to 12 times.
- `$` -> Ends with (no chars after).

Comment: `[0-9]` and `\d` are not the same in .NET. `\d` will match numerals from different scripts (Arabic, for instance), where `[0-9]` will not.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do:

```
^[0-9]{0,12}$
```

Thought this will also match on empty lines.

Comment: @nagarajub: which is what the OP wants?